# "Eject device" from command line

Tags: command-line, eject

For a cheap Chinese 3G modem, which has a builtin USB mass storage device with Windows drivers, I have a generic linux install manual that tells me to

> "Plug in your modem in USB port , on inserting you will notice icon on your desktop screen , right click on it and eject it.

However, my Ubuntu is a server without GUI. Which commands does the GUI call when I click "eject" on an USB mass storage device?

Comment: Try the answer below. It may not be enough. Usually, `usb_modeswitch` does that automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To eject the usb you can type in your terminal :

> eject /dev/sr0

where **sr0** is your device, it can be **sr1**,**sr2** **or** **/dev/sdb**,**/dev/sdc** and so on, its depends on your computer.

to show the device , just type in terminal :

`sudo fdisk -l` or `mount`

it will show the device.

Comment: 'mount' is probably a better command to run than fdisk, as it should be obvious. However, it's also plausible the device is not auto-mounted under Ubuntu Server, and so the _ejecting_ instructions can just be ignored.

Comment: try `lsblk` to list block device